# Set a variable's value to the integer on a line stored within a textfile

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a textfile called 'tx1.text'. In this textfile, I have written on each line a number,

64
73
86

etc

I have 3 variables in the program, 'one' 'two' 'three', how can I assign the variables the values in the textfile line by line?

Comment: three number in each of lines or just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
// Opne file and read all lines from file in string array
string[] values = File.ReadAllLines("tx1.txt");
// now get a number from string array and convert it to number
one = int.Parse(values[0]);
two = int.Parse(values[1]);
three = int.Parse(values[2]);
```

for further information about ReadAllLines method [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsy4fhsa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

if you've many lines in text file and don't know the exact number then use can use for loop to iterate through but in this case you also have to use List or Array of integers to store int values

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("tx1.txt");
// creates an array of length equal to total numbers
int[] numbers = new int[lines.Length];
// use for loop to convert and store each number in array
for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    numbers[i] = int.Parse(lines[i]);
}
```